# Session transfer between window and modal dialog

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, session

I have a parent window from which i open a modal dialog on button click. In WinXP with IE8 it works just fine, but in Win7 with IE8, upon opening the modal dialog it brings me to the login screen. If i enter my credentials, close the dialog and open it again, it works.

The explanation i figured out is that the session isn't transfered between parent and child.
The modal is opened with javascript window.open function.

I don't want to store the credentials in a cookie and then read it in my modal because it's a security no-no. Is there an explanation why this is happening in Win7 and not in XP and is there a resolution for this issue?

Comment: Is the modal window opened from another site/domain?

Comment: no... it's a web application hosted on a server, same site, same domain, same server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session resides on the server, so as long as the **browser** sees the modal dialog as the same site (server etc) it will identify itself to the server, which will then pull up the session details.  Perhaps you have cookies disabled somewhere.

Why don't you print out the session value on both screens?  Is it null the first time you open the modal dialog?

My guess is this is something do with an `if(IsPostPostBack)` in the modal dialog.  Other than that if you can post some code i'll certainly take a look.

Comment: thanks for the help, but i actually figured it out... It seems that on Win Vista and later window.open actually opens a new process and does not inherit the SessionID of the parent. So the solution would be either using showModalDialog or showModelessDialog. Either way for web applications, using window.open is not a good idea.

Comment: Ah so I was spot on then :-) "so as long as the browser sees the modal dialog as the same site (server etc) it will identify itself to the server" it obviously wasn't firing the correct cookies back to the server. Glad you got it fixed.

Comment: thanks... tip of the day: Don't use window.open unless it points to a site not related to your application